# Visual Studio + CMake's GLOB_RECURSE

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, include, cmake

I'm browsing a project which has a src directory similar to:

```
src/
|-- A.cpp
|-- dir/
|-- |-- B.h
|-- |-- B.cpp
```

In A.cpp they include B.h as such:

```
// In A.cpp:
#include "B.h"
```

In the visual studio 2010 solution generated with CMake this compiles just fine, and there exists no conflict. However, if I make a new project (not from CMake, but manually) and do the include as above, VS will not find B.h. I.e.:

```
// In A.cpp (non-CMake project version)
#include "B.h" // Error: File not found (VS does not search the
               //sub-directory when name is surrounded by "").
#include "dir/B.h" // Works: sub-directory specified.
```

The CMake file uses GLOB_RECURSE (which I assume is the reason the above works, please correct me if I'm wrong), and simplified it looks something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

project (cmake_test)

file(GLOB_RECURSE lib_SRCS RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp *.h)

include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir
)

add_library(lib STATIC
  ${lib_SRCS}
)

target_link_libraries(lib)
```

I've been examining the difference of the solution generated by CMake and the one I manually created, but I can't seem to find it.

My question is, in other words, how I could accomplish having VS find my B.h without the relative path included as the solution generated with CMake displays, without actually using CMake (such as by some option or configuration in my Visual Studio Project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that makes it work is

```
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/dir
)
```

Your `dir/` directory is added to the include directories.  In Visual Studio you need to go to project properties at `C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories` and add `dir/`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; that solved it for my own local project, but for some reason when I add a file to their project in the same fashion they have (with the already preexisting additional include directories) it once again claims to not find the file. My file and their files are both in a directory called "maps/" which is added to the C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories you described. Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: Where is maps?  src/maps? and src/dir?  in that case you would want to add "../dir" and "../maps" so files in maps and dir can find each other.  A good test is to add the full path to the include file and see if that works, then you can work out how to best use relative pathing to make things work.